# Second User On My Computer Via iCloud?

Tags: macos

**Disclaimer:** I have tried looking for an answer to this, but I couldn't find anything. I also am learning the basics of internet security and I have recently discovered the Objective See security apps for mac which are incredible...

https://objective-see.com/

(Not affiliated-just a fan)

For the last few months, I have suspected my computer had been hacked into. I noticed a lot of strange files etc. I restored computer recently, but I can still see suspicious activity in the Users>Library folder on my mac...

The objective see apps run a lot of processess, so I am sure they are partly responsible for someone of the new files. But there are still strange things I can't explain.

**Other iCloud Account**

The main issue is that there seems to be another iCloud account within my account. I cannot see it in iCloud settings, however when I follow this path I can see it:

*Users > Library > Application Support > Accounts > iCloud > Accounts*

I see my iCloud ID and then also this account number: 1810975846

When I click into the file, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVJB9.png

I did not edit this file at all, but when I foudn it today it said it has been created today...

I found this file on my computer and deleted it. But today I noticed it was back. I also noticed that the file has been created today - before I accessed it...

**Strange Files**

Another strange thing I noticed was:

-a folder called Ungeological.oi which was also included as launch daemon in my library folder

I don't have state secrets on my computer, but I am very conscious about people gaining to my information via iCloud. I also want to be absolutely sure people can't share my screen via strange launch daemon or anything.

If someone does have access to this folder, could I simply encrypt it? Or would there be a way of discovering password?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Exchange, unfortunately, I think this is a question for Apple support, not the site. Even if we give advice here we *cannot* actually do anything to help.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I have given that a try, but they weren't helpful. I'll try hackernews or reddit next